# ASP.NET Core: Azure Ad login not working on iPhone (Safari) browser. Fine on other browsers of windows

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
}
```

Appsetting.json

```
"AzureAd": {
       "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
       "Domain": "https://wasdfds.azurewebsites.net/",
       "ClientId": "sad-758f-44b0-8b84-asdf",
       "TenantId": "asdf-b571-4179-8c2a-asd",
       "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
       "LogoutUrl": "https://wasdfds.azurewebsites.net/signout-oidc"
     },
```

Comment: Ensure that the machine running the macOS is joined to AD.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sso-quick-start#browser-considerations

Comment: @CarlZhao Thanks i got solution

Comment: I am happy for you, would you mind sharing your approach?